# In cdk drag and drop I don't want to change the height of the box

Tags: angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have two lists one is for tasks and on the other side I have list to those I can assign. When I drag and drop the task to the next section it changes the height of the row which I don't want to change. Any helpful answer is appreciated.

I did read the documentation of CDK drag and drop but didn't get helpful answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.